# Bash error when trying to execute a file

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, executable

i am kinda new to linux and in programming so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm trying to run a basic program named **trial.c** with an executable file named **trying** but when I type **./trying** in the terminal this error comes up:

```
bash: ./trying: Permission denied
```

The folder is on my HDD with 3 partitions, one for home, another for my ubuntu_files, and the other is a fat32 partition named MISC. The folder is inside the fat32 partition of my HDD.

the problem is no matter how much I try to use `chown`and `chmod`(both with recursive) to change the permission of the folder containing the **trial.c** and the executable(**trying**) file, the bash error message would still stay the same.

The user is nciacrklo, and i typed `groups nciacrklo` to see what group is associated with that user and tried the codes found below in my terminal.

```
sudo chown nciacrklo:nciacrklo /media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb -R -v
```

and after that it said:

```
ownership of `/media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb/trying' retained as nciacrklo:nciacrklo 
ownership of `/media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb/trial.c' retained as nciacrklo:nciacrklo
```

and then,

```
sudo chmod 755 /media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb -R -v
```

it then said,

```
mode of `/media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb/trying' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
mode of `/media/nciacrklo/MISC/LibUsb/trial.c' changed from 0644 (rw-r--r--) to 0755 (rwxr-xr-x)
```

finally, I tried the `./trying` again but same error appeared.

```
bash: ./trying: Permission denied
```

please please help me I'm struggling with this and yet I have to do lots of programming about the LibUsb topic >.<.

any comments about how to use LibUsb to acquire pictures from webcam would also be much help. Thanks!!! \m/,

Comment: i am not sure but cant we use sudo here?

Comment: Run `chmod +x` on the file `./trying` - `chmod +x ./trying` - this should make it executable. Also, with the `trial.c` program, you may need to compile it first using `gcc` - look at `man gcc` in terminal. There is a great page on chmod [here](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html). The permissions of the file should not be `rw-r--r--`, but `rwxr--r-x` for it to execute *(I think - basically, it should have `x` in it somewhere)*.

Answer (score 2):

If all the permissions of the file are ok, as they seem to be, it might be because your partition is mounted with the `noexec` flag.

To check this: type `mount` and check if it is the case. You should see something like:

```
/dev/sdd1 on /media/banana type vfat (rw,noexec,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

(see the `noexec` there?)

Remount your partition with the `noexec` flag as so:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/banana
```

(you'll have to adapt the `banana` part to your case). And check that it worked by issuing `mount` again:

```
/dev/sdd1 on /media/banana type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

(no more `noexec` here!).

If that was your problem, you'll have to figure out the partition was mounted with the `noexec` flag in the first place.

Comment: Hi gniourf! thank you for taking the time to answer my question, but I'm still stuck with this error.

I followed what you said and I got this result by running `mount`:


`/dev/sda3 on /media/nciacrklo/MISC type vfat` 
`(rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,ut`
`f8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)`

but still I have this bash error.

Comment: @Carl, that's a known problem with udisk, that by default will mount vfat with the `showexec` option. You could either write your own udev rule (tedious), or unmount your volume, and remount it by hand: `mount /dev/sda3 /mount/point`.

Comment: okay. imma try it some other time. temporary fix is that I placed the file on my linux partition and run/edit it there. But thank you for this! I'll try it soon :)